# Can not ping host from guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, localhost

I have a Virtualbox setup whith a Windows 7 host and a Ubuntu 14.04.2 guest. I have set up a host-only adaptor because I want to be able to reach my hosts localhost ports.

I have set up the adaptor to have the

```
IP: 192.168.56.1 
Subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
```

The guest is set to

```
IP: 192.168.56.2 
Subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.56.1
```

I remember, this setup to be working fine. But now it doesn't. But I cant tell what changed since then.

**The Problem**: I can ping the guest from the host. But I can not ping the host from the guest. Both OSes ahev the correct IPs set to their interfaces (checked with `i(p/f)config`)

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Check that windows firewall is disabled for the network, or make rules to allow ping and other ports

Answer (score 0):

okay, I have now a solution.

The firewall was not the Problem.

It is working now, since I deactivated the WiFi Connection of my host. It had no active connection anyway. Please don't ask me, why this helped but it is working now.

Comment: was your wifi set to dhcp or a manual address? If it is purely down to your wifi, enabling it could cause a loss of connectivity. Try doing a route print next time to see if that shows any straw routing entries.